# Absolute values and integrability

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Determine using the definition, if the function $f : [−5, 5] → \mathbb{R}$,

$
  x \rightarrow  \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      1 & |x|\ = 0 \\
      2 & |x|\ \neq 1 \\
\end{array} 
\right. \
$

is integrable. What's the value of the integral if it is?

How should we go about integrability with the absolute values?

Comment: Well, basically, the value of the function is $2$ except in a set of measure $0$, so ...

Comment: This function is undefined for $x\in\{-1,1\}$ so how is it mapping $[-5,5]$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: That's a question I should probably ask my professor...

Comment: A sensible assumption is the one @MattiP. made: that $f(x)=2$ for $|x|\ne0$. Another good one would be $f(x)=2$ except for $|x|=1$.

Comment: I think the definition for Riemann integrable functions from our course book was " A bounded function $f : [a, b] → \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable, if $S_P = s_p$. " So i would just need to know the sup and inf of the function?